# VBA Selenium - Refresh the page to prove you are not a bot

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, webdriver, bots

I want my program in VBA to login on a website with chrome webdriver (with selenium) and perform some actions. Unfortunately the website asks me to prove I'm not a bot by refreshing the webpage after login. The problem is that even when I do so manually on the webdriver (to test), it doesn't work and the website won't let me move forward.

I have the feeling that if I open and interact with the website through an existing open browser, the website will not recognize me as a bot. But i cannot manage to do it. I am open to any other solution.

This is how my code starts:

```
Sub testchrome()
   Dim obj As New WebDriver
   Dim Keys As New Keys

   obj.Start "chrome"
   obj.Get "https://freebitcoin.io"
End Sub
```

And then I just perform my business (login etc.).

I would be so grateful if you have any idea not to be detected as a bot or manage to pass this verification step. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: it sounds like you are asking how to get a handle on a non automated browser session with selenium - I don't think you can. I assume you tried the inbuilt .Refresh method?

Comment: So you are trying to bypass a "prove you are not a bot" system so that you can use a bot? That's not possible. That's why those systems are implemented, to prevent people from creating automated systems like you are trying to do.

Comment: Use a REST API if there's one. What you're doing is very likely against the ToS of the website you're hitting, and can get you IP-banned.

Answer (score 0):

This will refresh the page:

```
obj.Navigate().Refresh()
```

But that said, i'm not sure if a refresh will accomplish what you think it will.

> I have the feeling that if I open and interact with the website
>   through an existing open browser, the website will not recognize me as
>   a bot.

Selenium doesn't "reuse" a browser session that you already have open on your computer.

I think you'd have to interact with the OS itself to control the browser.

Comment: Not sure that is correct syntax for vba where (not tested) I think you may just be able to do driver.refresh.... also, you can connect to an existing session if that session was launched with selenium (basic)